# Shell grep XML content based on tag

Tags: xml, bash, grep

I have a xml file from which I want to extract the content inside of two xml tags similar to this:

```
<foo id="001">
... any String ...
</foo>
```

The starting tag line is unique due to the identifier, but the closing tag can appear any number of times. Is there a way to output the String inside those two tags using `grep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this magic:

```
grep -oPz '(?s)<foo id="001".*?</foo>\n' file.xml
```

where:

- -o Print  only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
- -P Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).
- -z Treat  input  and  output  data  as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.
- (?s) Enabled PCRE_DOTALL
- .*? Makes the match non-greedy (minimal).

Comment: Nice magic ! Why I can't see the zero byte in the output when I do `grep ... | xxd`

Comment: I just updated the description as I think I copied the description for-Z instead -z.  To answer your question, I think it's because the input doesn't contain any NULs, but you need the option to override the default \n line separator.